# Plotly: Visualize addressess on the geographical map with gradient colors

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly, data-visualization, geospatial

Sample dataset I have looks like this:

| ID | Neighborhood | Rate (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Upper Manhattan | 2 |
| 2 | Marble Hill | 14 |
| 3 | Hamilton Heights | 8 |
| 4 | ... | ... |

I need to visualize df['Neigboorhood'] column with scaled colors that are given based on df['Rate (%)'] column

I expect it to look like this:

[image]

Based on my research on the web, I can create such map, but for this i need to convert Neighborhood column to geospatial format. However, i have no aptitudes and longitudes given. How can I achieve this chart?

Comment: personally I don't have much experience in this area, but you might consider looking [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/client-library) to start